# Is passing this lambda to `unique_ptr` OK for lifetime?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I come up with code like this.

Is passing this lambda to `unique_ptr` in method `ptr` OK for lifetime?

```
#include <memory>

#include <cstdlib>

#include <cstdio>

struct MallocAllocator{
    static void *allocate(size_t size) noexcept{
        return malloc(size);
    }

    /* static */ void deallocate(void *p) noexcept{
        printf("%d\n", x); // debug
        return free(p);
    }

    template<class T>
    auto ptr(T *p){
        auto x = [me = this](T *p){
            me->deallocate(p);
        };

        return std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(x)>{ p, x };
    }

    int x; // debug

    MallocAllocator(int x) : x(x){}
};

MallocAllocator allocator{5};

int *getInt(MallocAllocator &allocator){
    return (int *) allocator.allocate(sizeof(int));
}

int main(){
    auto a = allocator.ptr( getInt(allocator) );
}
```

Comment: Please don't change critical details after a question is answered; the change you made invalidates @ypnos' answer.

Comment: really? what is the difference? In both cases I capture "external" pointer.

Comment: No, the `allocator` that was passed was a reference and `me = & allocator` would capture a pointer to that reference, *not* to what it points to.

Comment: Note that in your current version, you could simplify by capturing `[this]` and then just calling `deallocate(p);` (the use of `this` is implicit)

Comment: pass by reference, keep the address unchanged. when i do & i get the original address, exactly the same as it would if i capture this pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda is an object and you can store it how you see fit. You need to ensure the lifetime of any references or pointers it holds though.

If you capture by copy (`=`) you are always on the safe side. In your example, you capture `this` pointer, which is also fine if the object will outlive your unique_ptr (the case here as it is a global object).

Note that it is a fallacy to capture local pointers or references by pointer/reference because these fall out of scope and get invalid, even if the object they point to outlives:

```
auto ref = this;
auto lambda = [&] () { this->… }; // ok if parent object outlives lambda
auto lambda = [&] () { ref->… }; // wrong! leads to invalid pointer
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MSalters Yes that code was probably wrong, he captured a pointer to a reference, and the reference would fall out of scope and be gone..

Comment: @ypnos: True, question changed as did your answer. Deleting old comment.

Comment: in my previous edit, I capture pointer to reference that comes from outside. I edited the code so is mere clear what i do. In both cases I am capturing one and same thing. Before edit I realized I pass this pointer manually as reference.